# Count number of repeating elements in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

This program is for counting number of occurrences of each unique element.
Output is:

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int *input;
    int n,c;

    printf("Enter the number of elements in the array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    input = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter %d elements \n",n);
    for(c=0; c<n; c++)
        scanf("%d",input+c);//POINTER NOTATION

    if (sizeof(input) == 0) return 0;

    int prev = input[0];
    int count = 1;
    int i;
    int ARRAYSIZE = sizeof(input) / sizeof(int);

    for (i = 1; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) 
    {

        if (input[i] == prev)
        {
            count++;
        } 
        else 
        {
            printf("%d=%d ", prev, count);
            prev = input[i];
            count = 1;
        }

    }

    printf("%d=%d\n", prev, count);
    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Enter the number of elements in the array:10

Enter 10 elements

1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 6

1=1

Here I have entered 1 (5 times), 2 (2 times), 3 (2 times) and 6 (once)
But as you can see it only gives 1=1(1 times, but I've entered 1 five times.)
Can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: I'll probably sort the input data, will use sorting techniques. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to write a new algorithm which counts non consecutive elements.

Comment: When you run it in your debugger, what happens?

Comment: Note `sizeof(input) == 0` is never true.  The size of a pointer is always more than 0.

Comment: Note that your code is vulnerable to faulty inputs — you don't check that the `scanf()` operations succeeded, or that the entered value is sane (not a negative or zero count, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need this:

```
int ARRAYSIZE = sizeof(input) / sizeof(int);
```

Use `n` in place of `ARRAYSIZE`.

`sizeof(input)` returns the size of the pointer, `input`, not the size of the array. The `for` loop is not executed, the output is from the outer `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program works with just some small changes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *input;
    int n, c;

    printf("Enter the number of elements in the array:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    input = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    printf("Enter %d elements \n", n);
    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
        scanf("%d", input + c);//POINTER NOTATION

    int prev = input[0];
    int count = 1;
    int i;
    int ARRAYSIZE = n;

    for (i = 1; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {

        if (input[i] == prev) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            printf("%d=%d ", prev, count);
            prev = input[i];
            count = 1;
        }

    }

    printf("%d=%d\n", prev, count);
    free(input);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Enter the number of elements in the array:10
Enter 10 elements 
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 6
1=5 2=2 3=2 6=1

Process finished with exit code 0
```